# Go up one "folder" or segment in jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, back

If I'm, for example, on this page

```
www.example.com/admin/bridge/boilerplate
```

What is the best way (Using plain javascript, or jQuery (Without loading another plugin) to go up one level, e.g.

```
www.example.com/admin/bridge
```

At the moment we are using

```
window.history.go(-1);
```

which interferes with submitted forms, etc.
This is used  normally on a function like this:

```
$("button.cancel").bind("click", function( e ){
    window.history.go(-1);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple:

```
var url = window.location.href;

if (url.substr(-1) == '/') url = url.substr(0, url.length - 2);

url = url.split('/');
url.pop();

window.location = url.join('/');
```

Comment: I rarely add comments, but this solution was so simple and elegant, I just had to, good job on this haha.

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/");
window.location = window.location.href.substr(0,i)
```

Comment: You'll have to polyfill `lastIndexOf` for older versions of IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf

Comment: @JosephSilber true, neither of these two answers will work if there's a `'/'` in the hash segment of the url though

Comment: Fixed my answer to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

thanks, but this edited:

```
$("#back a").click(function() {
    var url = window.location.href;

    if (url.substr(-1) == '/') url = url.substr(0, url.length - 2);

    url = url.split('/');
    url.pop();

    window.location = url.join('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

window.history is actually manipulating what is in your browser history, it is what the back/forward buttons in the browser use.

So, if the only way to get to the directory you are in is to navigate to it by digging down through the parent directories, this would work.  However, that is never the only way to get to a page.  Users are always able to bookmark the page.